# how to add users in a group in sharepoint 2013 through program

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-2007

I am making a window application in which when some body enters the ID of the user than it will get automatically added in Usergroup.I am making a window application Code as follows:

```
Imports Microsoft.SharePoint.Client
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1


    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        ClientContext ClientContext = New ClientContext("http://ServerName/Pages/Default.aspx")

    End Sub
End Class
```

Now I am getting error Saying Client Context  is a type and Cannot used as expression.How do i add url using Client Context/I am using Vb.net in VS2015.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here what I see is in the name of the variable. Try giving the name _clientContext and in the method pass the url of you sharepoint site not page

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    ClientContext _clientContext= New ClientContext("<siteUrl>")

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/code/2629/add-users-to-group-in-sharepoint-2013-using-csom.aspx